# Windows deduplication file "cores" parameter is not recognized

Tags: windows, server, parameters, duplicates

I'm using deduplication file on my windows server 2012 R2, but the dedup-jobs is very long and consume less than 5% of the CPU. I would like that jobs consume more CPU, so i try to use the "--cores" parameter but i've an error which this parameter is not recognized.

Here is my command :

```
Start-Dedupjob -Type GarbageCollection -Volume D: -Cores 50
```

Why isn't the cores parameter being recognized? How can I have this command take advantage of the other cores to speed up the job?

Comment: Nobody can help me ? :'(

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is RTFM... This parameter is available only since Windows Server 2016.